# HTML/CSS slideshow in background?

Tags: html, css, background, slideshow

I wrote HTML source for a slideshow on a website. I want the slideshow to be in the background (i.e full screen and *behind* the text) but even with my `max-width`, etc. set at 100% it doesn't stay full screen and I have no idea how to make sure it stays behind everything else. 
Here is the `main_rjfe.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>R. J. Farah Engineering</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main_rjfe.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="box fade-in logo">
            <img src="logo.png" style="width:270px;height:128px;">
        </div>
        <div class="menu_box fade-in menu"> 
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="css-slideshow"> 
            <figure> 
                <img src="img1.jpg" width="495" height="370" /> 
                <figcaption><strong>CSS3:</strong> CSS3 delivers a...</figcaption> 
            </figure> 
            <figure> 
                <img src="img2.jpg" width="495" height="370" /> 
            <figcaption><strong>Semantics:</strong> Giving meaning to...</figcaption> 
            </figure> 
            <figure> 
                <img src="img3.jpg" width="495" height="370" /> 
            <figcaption><strong>Semantics:</strong> Giving meaning to...</figcaption> 
            </figure> 

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my `CSS` file:

```
/*Slideshow*/
.css-slideshow{
   position: absolute;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   margin: auto;
}
.css-slideshow figure{
   margin: 0;
   position: absolute;
}
.css-slideshow figcaption{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   color: #fff;
   background: rgba(0,0,0, .3);
   font-size: .8em;
   padding: 8px 12px;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity .5s;
}
.css-slideshow:hover figure figcaption{
   transition: opacity .5s;
   opacity: 1;
}
.css-slideshow figure{
   opacity:0;
}

figure:nth-child(1) {
   animation: xfade 18s 12s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(2) {
   animation: xfade 18s 6s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(3) {
   animation: xfade 18s 0s infinite;
}
@keyframes xfade{
   0%{
      opacity: 0;
   }
   32% {
      opacity:1;
   }
   33%{
      opacity: 0;
   }
   98% {
      opacity:0;
   }
   100% {
      opacity:1;
   }
}
```

There is more in the `.css` file, but the StackOverflow questions guidelines say to put only the code that I think is causing the problem. If you need the rest of the file, comment and I will update the question. 
Thanks!!

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to a working example, where you're experiencing the problem? That would be the easiest way to tell where you have issues.

Comment: @Wellspring sorry, i don't. im bulding the website, but I haven't launched it or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: first is that if you want the images at 100%, you have to set them like

```
figure img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

You should also do this for the figure tag:

```
figure {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The second is that you should consider making them background images, as the slideshow is in the background anyways, and just transition the containing divs.

Finally, you need to make sure that your figure tags are not inside any relative container, otherwise their absolute dimensions will be pinned to that container.